# firebase authentication with React context api, tracking user id in localStorage

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-context

I try to develop a non-commercial React app with firestore authentication.
My context which provides me state of user whether it is logged in or logged out:

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
 const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

 useEffect(() => {
   authentication.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
   setCurrentUser(user);
 });
 }, []);

return (
 <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser }}>
  {children}
 </AuthContext.Provider>
 );
};
```

I wrapped my components with provider which is described above.
When a user logged in or signed up, I store its user id in localStorage with;

```
localStorage.setItem("userId", cred.user.uid);
```

Then, when I need to get currentUser in my components I use;

```
const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
const userId = currentUser ? currentUser.uid : localStorage.getItem("userId");
```

If I do not use localStorage to store user id, when user refresh the page I cannot get user id because context does not provide me currentUser state.

Storing user id in localStorage does not seem safe and a proper way to me. I wonder the best practice of keeping track of user informations with firebase authentication and react. Looking for help, thanks in advance !

Comment: you shouldn't have to store the user id in local storage, because everytime you refresh the onAuthStateChanged listener will fire again, setting the currentUser.  You will need to wait for the currentUser to be defined again on refresh

Comment: @RobertTerrell thank you so much for your comment ! I understood what do you mean and I tried it. You are right. I defined a loading state in context to see in other components whether onAuthStateChanged listener fired and set currentUser. It works. It may be a better way than storing info in localStorage. But ın this way, I will have to render my components according to this loading state and my structure is just a bit complex. So it will make structure much more complex. But in anyway thank you for your comment, maybe there are still better ways to handle this issue.

Comment: no problem! I think you can place a loading state where your routes are defined, I'm assuming your app.js and set up an if statement that will render a loader or something along those lines if your app is in the loading state.  this way your app won't render until your current user is ready

Comment: @RobertTerrell you helped me so much, thanks a lot ! yes, wrapping my all routes is a great way to do this, I will implement it.